# How to convert time variable into numeric variable in R

Tags: r, date, datetime

I have got a date formatted file that contains date format column in the following format

```
4\8    # April 8th, 2013
7\12   # July 12th, 2013
```

All these dates are default in 2013,  Now I want to create a column that specify the number of days since 4\1\2013  (April 1st, 2013), for April 8th, it is 8.

How should I proceed?  I should use fill in 2013 as prefix then use `as.Date` function in R? But then it seems I should replace "\" by "/"

OK, I want to summarize @rawr's solution so that others can follow

First, I need to change from "\" to "//" for reading format requirement by R

Second, I need append 2013 to the end of string, the trick here is to execute `paste0(dates, "\\")` first (I figured out this myself! ) before executing `dates <- paste0(dates, '\\2013')` to ensure there are two "\" before 2013, otherwise there will be always just one escape symbol before 2013.

Third, execute `as.Date("6\\\\4\\\\2013", format = '%m\\\\%d\\\\%Y')`, or something like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\` is an escape character, so R won't like `4\8`, so you need to use `\\` for a single `\`

```
> cat('\\')
\
```

here is one way to do it:

```
dates
# [1] "4\\8"  "7\\12"
dates <- paste0(dates, '\\2013')
# [1] "4\\8\\2013"  "7\\12\\2013"
as.Date(dates, format = '%m\\%d\\%Y') - as.Date('2013-04-01') + 1
# Time differences in days
# [1]   8 103
as.numeric(as.Date(dates, format = '%m\\%d\\%Y') - as.Date('2013-04-01') + 1)
# [1]   8 103
```

Comment: your command    dates <- paste0(dates, '\\2013') gives format like "4\\8\2013", in other words, only one escape symbol between date and year

Comment: your follow up command still did not work, I checked class(dates) in my original data, it is of factor

Comment: convert them to character with `as.character()`. Or when making a df, use `data.frame(..., stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`. I would guess `as.Date` would be converting the factors to numeric (which would give 1, 2, 3, etc) and then to dates

Comment: I did try as.character() before and after paste0 commands, both will give only one escape sign before the year 2013

Comment: OK, I add a separate dates <- paste0(dates, '\\') command before dates <- paste0(dates, '\\2013'), now I get date format correct. However, as.Date(dates, format = '%m\\%d\\%Y') - as.Date('2013-04-01') gives me NAs

Comment: what is the `str(dates)`

Comment: start at the beginning with your original `dates`, also you can work with any weird format: `as.Date("6\\\\4\\\\2013", format = '%m\\\\%d\\\\%Y')`